# How can I append to a select drop down that lives on another page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm working on creating a service that allows you to create team or user based challenges. Using HTML 5 specifications to design the page, I've run into a bit of an issue appending to a drop down list that resides in another page. The entirety of functionality lives within two pages, mainly by making AJAX calls to other pages. There's a little function that appends 2 properties of a team to a drop down list, but I can't seem to get it to work properly.

Code:

```
var teams = $.parseJSON(getAllTeams());
    $('#multiPurpose').load('allTeams2.html #teamSelect');
    for (i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
        var team = $.parseJSON(getTeam(teams[i]));
        if (team.ownerID === userID) {
            $(
                    "<option value='" + team.teamID + "'>" + team.teamName
                            + "</option>").appendTo('#teamSelection');
        }
    }
}
```

The #teamSelection is contained within the #teamSelect div. Any help would be great.

Comment: Stupid question: are you certain that #teamSelection is actually there?  In other words, if you do `console.log($('#teamSelection'))` just before your appendTo, do you actually see it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a callback function within .load() will solve the problem. Basically, you're telling it to load everything within that div before running the for loop.

```
$('#multiPurpose').load(
    'allTeams2.html #teamSelect',
    function() {
    for (i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
    var team = $.parseJSON(getTeam(teams[i]));
    if (team.ownerID === userID) {
    $(
    "<option value='" + team.teamID + "'>"
                                            + team.teamName + "</option>")
                                    .appendTo('#teamSelection');
                        }
                    }
                });
```